# Django: Hotel Reservation database start_date and end_date

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model that looks something like this

```py
Class Reservation(models.Model):
   room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
   start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
   end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
   person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="people")
```

A Room can have multiple reservation and a reservation can take multiple people.

I want to the `availability` spaces in a given room over the next 30 days.

availability is simply total number of people a room can take - total number of people in active rentals.

This is so that users booking a new rental know how many people a room can take.

**Expected Results**

```
{

    "22-Jul-2021": 5,
    "23-Jul-2021": 2,
    "24-Jul-2021": 5,
    "25-Jul-2021": 3,
    "26-Jul-2021": 8,
    "27-Jul-2021": 1,

}
```

Comment: An SQL query might also fix this issue

Comment: An usecase is AirBnB's reservation availability system

Answer (score 0):

- Availability model with a date field, an integer for the number of guests available for that specific date and a FK field to Reservation;

```
class Availability(models.Model):
    current_date = models.DateField()
    quantity_guests = models.IntegerField()
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation)
```

You can override the ***models.Manager*** for the `Room`class and create a customized listing method that will return a result exactly how you want it to be.

To know more about how to do this I would take a look at the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) and on tutorials such as [this](https://djangocentral.com/adding-custom-model-managers-in-django/) one.

In  the  end it will look something like:

```
class RoomManager(models.Manager):
    def list_availabilities(self...):
        # put your code to query the room and its availabilities here and return a queryset of it...
        return super().get_queryset().filter(........)



class Room(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = RoomManager()

    ...
```